# Splitting the date alongside pivot_wider

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, pivot, spread

I've the following table.

| Date | Cat |
| --- | --- |
| 15/2/1999 | A |
| 15/2/1999 | A |
| 15/2/1999 | B |
| 15/5/1999 | A |
| 15/5/1999 | B |
| 15/10/1999 | C |
| 15/10/1999 | C |
| 15/2/2001 | A |
| 15/2/2001 | A |
| 15/6/2001 | B |
| 15/6/2001 | B |
| 15/6/2001 | C |
| 15/11/2001 | C |
| 15/11/2001 | C |

I would like to apply pivot_wider (or any other similar functions) to it and also accounting for the Date and Year column as seen below. The Cat column is being split based on the variable A, B and C and the count is being displayed.

| Month | Year | A | B | C | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| February | 1999 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| May | 1999 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| October | 1999 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| February | 2001 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| June | 2001 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| November | 2001 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

Does anyone here knows how I can do both together? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `tidyverse` packages. First, format your date column as date, then count by month, pivot to wider and format the table.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(Cat, month = lubridate::floor_date(Date, "month")) %>% 
  count(Cat) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cat, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(month), .before = "A",
         month = month(month, label = T, abbr = F)) %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(across(A:C))) %>% 
  arrange(year)

  month     year     A     B     C Total
  <ord>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 February  1999     2     1     0     3
2 May       1999     1     1     0     2
3 October   1999     0     0     2     2
4 February  2001     2     0     0     2
5 June      2001     0     2     1     3
6 November  2001     0     0     2     2
```

data

```r
data <- structure(list(Date = c("15/2/1999", "15/2/1999", "15/2/1999", 
"15/5/1999", "15/5/1999", "15/10/1999", "15/10/1999", "15/2/2001", 
"15/2/2001", "15/6/2001", "15/6/2001", "15/6/2001", "15/11/2001", 
"15/11/2001"), Cat = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("15/2/1999",
           "15/2/1999","15/2/1999","15/5/1999","15/5/1999",
           "15/10/1999","15/10/1999","15/2/2001","15/2/2001",
           "15/6/2001","15/6/2001","15/6/2001","15/11/2001",
           "15/11/2001"),
  Cat = c("A","A","B","A",
          "B","C","C","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), Year = year(dmy(Date))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Month, Year), names_from = Cat,
       values_from = Cat, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[3:5]))

#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   Month  Year     A     B     C Total
#>   <ord> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Feb    1999     2     1     0     3
#> 2 May    1999     1     1     0     2
#> 3 Oct    1999     0     0     2     2
#> 4 Feb    2001     2     0     0     2
#> 5 Jun    2001     0     2     1     3
#> 6 Nov    2001     0     0     2     2
```